# GPyTorch, how to set initial value for "lengthscale" hyperparameter?

Tags: kernel, hyperparameters, gpytorch

I am using GPyTorch regressor according to the [documentation](https://docs.gpytorch.ai/en/stable/examples/01_Exact_GPs/Simple_GP_Regression.html).

I would like to set an initial value for the "lengthscale" hyperparameter in RBF kernel.

I want to set a constant number as initial value for "lengthscale" (similar to what we can do in scikit-learn Gaussian Process Regressor).

If you have any idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two cases that follow from your question:

1. **You want to initialize your lengthscale with some value but the lengthscale is then optimized on further by the optimizer**

   Assuming you have the same model as given in the documentation you have linked, just add the following before your training loop:

   ```
   init_lengthscale = 0.1
   model.covar_module.base_kernel.lengthscale = init_lengthscale
   ```

   The `model.covar_module` gets your entire kernel and the `base_kernel` gets you your
   RBF kernel.
2. **You want to fix your lengthscale as some constant value which will not be further optimized**

   In addition to the code for the first case, you do not feed the lengthscale as a hyperparameter to be optimized to your optimizer.

   ```
   all_params = set(exactModel.parameters())
   final_params = list(all_params - {exactModel.covar_module.base_kernel.raw_lengthscale})
   optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(final_params, lr=0.1)
   ```

   We remove the set of raw lengthscale values from `all_params` to create `final_params` which we then pass to the optimizer.

Some sources to help:

- https://github.com/cornellius-gp/gpytorch/issues/689
- https://docs.gpytorch.ai/en/v1.1.1/examples/00_Basic_Usage/Hyperparameters.html

Comment: Thank you. In which part of the code I should use "model.covar_module.base_kernel.lengthscale = init_lengthscale"? Is it after initializing the model by "model = ExactGPModel(train_x, train_y, likelihood)"?

Comment: @Mohammad: Yes. You should be able to use it anywhere after initializing the model and before starting the training loop. It should obviously be outside of the training loop.

Comment: Regarding @aiish 's reply, (point 1) how could one output the length scale's optimization values over iterations?